# Perfmon not collecting Logical disk counter data

Tags: performance-monitoring

We have a central management server on which we collect Baselines for remote servers. Baseline includes perfmon counters like logical disk, SQL server buffer manager, physical disk, network interface etc. We save it to a SQL server database.

The problem is, it is not collecting data for logical disk for 1 server. To check that there is no problem with counters on this server, I created a server specific baseline to collect only the logical disk counters for this server remotely. It collected counter data just fine. this server specific baseline is running under same credentials as the full baseline.

Server specifications: Windows server 2003 R2 standard (64 bit) edition
Management Server specifications: Windows server 2003 enterprise edition

Any help why it is not working for the full baseline? I have dropped and added the counters manually but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do disk counters need to be enabled on w2k3 if so look at diskperf command for the syntax

Comment: But they do work on a standalone counter log. So they are enabled isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround- created seperate counter log. It might be because there are too many counters in that counter log...